# Launch Chrome full screen to a specific URL using PowerShell?

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, fullscreen

How do I launch a Chrome browser in a full screen window with a specific URL as the webpage to open using PowerShell?

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --start-fullscreen "http://www.google.com"
```

The above command gives an error:

> "Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
> argument 'http://www.google.com'."

I have tried with and without the quotations too.

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://www.google.com"
```

The above open the page but will not display it full screen

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --start-fullscreen
```

Will open the browser but just to the start page.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!
For some reason combining the full screen and the URL option are causing me fits.  What am I doing wrong?



For further information, what I am trying to accomplish is this:  Open a browser full screen to a specific page, check to see if a screen shot exists, remove it if it does, save a  screen shot, close the browser.

So far everything works except for full screen.

Comment: try `start "title" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --start-fullscreen "http://www.google.com"`

Comment: Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like "My Script" or just a pair of empty quotes ""
According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but depending on the other options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted.

Comment: Thank you David, I will remember that!

Comment: Kiosk mode can be useful when you don't want to allow the user access to the rest of the computer. See [how to setup kiosk mode in chrome](https://www.appsadmins.com/blog/chrome-kiosk-mode-introduction)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are running with PowerShell, "start" is an alias for the `Start-Process` command. With PowerShell `Start-Process` requires the `-ArgumentList` parameter to specify what values you are passing as arguments separately than the process which is [started] executed.

Basically, you just need to enclose the `--start-fullscreen "http://www.google.com"` in single quotes and make it the value of the `-ArgumentList` parameter of PowerShell `Start-Process`

### PowerShell

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -ArgumentList '--start-fullscreen "http://www.google.com"'
```

### Alias using shorter PowerShell

```
Start "C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" '--start-fullscreen "http://www.google.com"'
```

## Supporting Resources

- [Start-Process](https://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Start-Process: `saps`, `start`

Comment: Thank you for this!  This worked perfectly.

Comment: You are welcome @Jaymes!

Comment: Handy tip: include `C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application` in your `$env:PATH` and you can simply run `chrome.exe` from anywhere without the full path.

Comment: What if you don't know where Chrome is installed? Google moves it.